# DRUPAL 8.7 ERROR The taxonomy_term.XXXX field must be updated

Tags: drupal-8

I tried to run drush entity update but from version 8.7 it doesn't work.

Drupal Version: 8.9.1

PHP Version: 7.3.7

Database Version: 5.6.48-log Sistema
MySQL, MariaDB, Percona Server, o equivalenti

Error:

definitions entity / field

Mismatching of entity and / or field definitions

The following changes were noted in the entity and field type definitions.

Taxonomy term

- The taxonomy_term.field_catalogo_pdf field must be updated.
- The taxonomy_term.field_categoria_subtitol field must be updated.
- The taxonomy_term.field_coll_img field needs to be updated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Devel Entity Updates](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates) contributed module and run the following commands:

```
$ drush en devel_entity_updates -y
$ drush entup -y
```

Comment: The commands drush devel_entity_update don't work for version 8.7 Drupal.

Comment: Yes, you need to jnstall the contrib module now. See the link in the answer